# Powershell - FTP - Get-WebConfiguration to retrieve details of users

Tags: powershell, iis, configuration, ftp

I am using this command to set the users access on an FTP site:

```
Add-WebConfiguration "/system.ftpServer/security/authorization" -value @{accessType="Allow";roles="";permissions="Read,Write";users="*"} -PSPath IIS:\ -location $SiteName
```

I want to be able to use Get-WebConfiguration to be able to retrieve what user/users have access and use an If /Else block to be able to add the users if they don't already exist. I cant seem to come up with the correct syntax to make this work??

I can use this and it will get the users and their permissions:

```
Get-WebConfiguration "/system.ftpserver/security/authorization" -Location $SiteName  | Foreach{$_.GetCollection() | Foreach {$_.Attributes | Format-Table name, value} }
```

How do I format this string to be able to get the actual users as an object that I can use in an If / Else statement?

Basically - If '$user' already has access move on Else "Add-WebConfiguration..... as in my first line of code that works fine"

Thanks

pelagos

Comment: Capture the result of `Get-WebConfiguration` and **replace** the last ForEach with `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Attributes`. Then you can filter out users with or without permissions on that variable with a `Where-Clause`. Never use `Format-Table` is your intention is to actually DO something with the result. Only use that for displaying stuff to the console.

Comment: Thanks very much! - Yeah I was only using the Format-Table to to try and work through the problem